# Remove and bring back RecordTypes in Managed Packages

Tags: managed-package, record-type, remove

We are about to remove all the RecordTypes on some of our packaged objects.
The consequence is, that also the RecordTypeId field will be removed.
Feels right so far. I am just wondering if I am able to bring record types back on that object one day
because as we know deleted fields can never be brought back when there were deleted once in a managed package. Does this restriction also apply to standard fields, especially the RecordTypeId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard fields are not subject to the reusability rule. That's because standard fields (e.g. OwnerId, CurrencyIsoCode, and RecordTypeId) aren't actually deleted, but instead just hidden. Keep in mind, though, that you can't reuse API names, so if you delete all the record types, you won't be able to use those names in future versions of the package.